# Boost build/install issue Windows

Tags: windows, boost, installation

I am trying to build boost on windows. I downloaded both version 1.53 and 1.54 and having the same issue.

I navigate to boost root dir from cmd prompt. and run "booststrap.bat" file
Using 'vc11' toolset.

then i attempt to run:

C:\Boost\boost_1_53_0>.\b2 -prefix=c:\Boost -build-type=complete -with-thread -with-regex -with-system -with-date_time -with-test -with-filesystem -with-chrono -with-program_options address-model=32 install
C:/Boost/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\property.jam:328: in validate1 from module property
error: Invalid property '<ûprefix>c:\Boost': unknown feature 'ûprefix'.
C:/Boost/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\property.jam:337: in property.validate from module property
C:/Boost/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\build-request.jam:216: in convert-command-line-element from module build-request
C:/Boost/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build\build-request.jam:154: in build-request.from-command-line from module build-request
C:/Boost/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:613: in load from module build-system
C:\Boost\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
C:\Boost\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
C:\Boost\boost_1_53_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module

C:\Boost\boost_1_53_0>

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Boost building problems are a tragedy.  I suspect you won't get anywhere until you figure out how ûprefix got that funny hat on the letter u.  Your SO user name and your profile doesn't help us figure out where you live so no lead whatsoever on an encoding problem.  Don't program alone.

Comment: Sorry, Im located in the U.S.

Comment: Seriously, ensure that you put a regular hyphen (minus) in `.\b2 -prefix=`. Make sure your keyboard layout is US english.